# NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code - declaring Excel.Worksheet object

Tags: vb.net

I'm transitioning from Excel VBA to VB.NET, so if this is a dumb question, please go easy on me.  I get a `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code` on this line of the following sub:

```
Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet = objBook.Sheets("SQL Creator")
```

VS says that the `Object reference is not set to an instance of the object`.  I'm not sure why it's asking for that, because I've already declared a new instance of Excel in the objApp variable.  Why would I need to declare a new instance of each object under that class?  It's very possible I'm not thinking about that correctly, but I just wanted to mention my thoughts.  Overall, I'm just trying to test the sub below to see if it will open and close a connection to a PostgreSQL database.

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

```
    Public Sub QueryData(ByVal ribbonUI As Office.IRibbonControl)

            Dim objApp As New Excel.Application
            Dim objBook As Excel.Workbook = objApp.ActiveWorkbook
            Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet = objBook.Sheets("SQL Creator")
            Dim pgconn As String

            pgconn = "Driver={PostgreSQL};" &
            "Server = localhost;" &
            "Port = 5432;" &
            "Database = CFABudget;" &
            "Uid = postgres;" &
            "Pwd = budgeto;"

            Dim SQL As String = objSheet.Range("BudgetSQL").Text
            Dim conn As New Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(pgconn)
            Dim cmd As Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand = New Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(SQL)

            conn.Open()

            MsgBox("Success!", vbOKOnly)

            conn.Close()


        End Sub
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`Dim objApp As New Excel.Application`

With:

`Dim objApp As Excel.Application = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")`

You were trying to get active workbook from new empty instance of excel.